# How to tweet message on logeed in user profile

Tags: php, posts, tweets

I Have integrated tweeter connect with my website.I have used oauth code to post on tweeter.
I have mentioned part of the code what I have used below.

```
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);
// Your Message
$message = "hi I am fine";
// Send tweet     
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));
```

But I can not post on the user page who is logged in ,It only shows on application's user page, should I add anything with this code?if so please let me know what should I do with code.

Comment: Make sure that you've granted the permission to post on the user's wall.

Comment: Where I can give permission to post on the user's wall

Comment: whether I have to change setting from application which I have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is alright. It will work.

But the main thing is to figure out what is the error and why it's not working. Simply replace

```
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));
```

using:

```
$mytweet=$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));
var_dump($mytweet); 
// print the output coming from the post request, that you done using twitterOauth
```

I already have used the same code, first time it's not working as my **Application was Read Only Type** and now works properly! So, make sure your Application settings is **Read and Write** type at least. Here the solution in details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035906/tweeting-with-php-not-working/18036339#18036339

Answer (score 2):

I have done this through JS. That may be helpful to you.

code was something like this :

SHARE WITH TWITTER :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function twitter_click()
{u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(
'http://twitter.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer',
'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return twitter_click()">
<img alt="twittershare" src="http://lh6.ggpht.com/_iEnxos6ddpE/Tb6BVrptRVI/AAAAAAAACaU/XQ0dT77GozI/tweetsip.gif"/></a>
```

SHARE WITH FACEBOOK :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click()
{u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(
'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer',
'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return fbs_click()">
<img alt="facebook share" src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/_iEnxos6ddpE/Tb6BUD0OGfI/AAAAAAAACaQ/0pd1LCCkPDs/SukaFB.gif"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what I need is the post should be done automatically through my site when user review any post or something like that I don't want to  let user post manually